# Polynomials Multiplication in One Variable

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there an efficient way/algorithm to extract coefficients in product of K polynomials in one variable? Eg: $ P_1(x) = p_{10} + p_{11}x + ... + p_{1n}x^n$
$P_2(x) = p_{20} + p_{21}x + ... + p_{2n}x^n $
.
.
.

$P_K(x) = p_{k0} + p_{k1}x + ... + p_{kn}x^n $

So how to get the coefficients of product of these polynomials: 
$ P(x) = \prod_i P_i(x) $

Answer (score 0):

The coefficient in $P(x)$ of the $j^\text{th}$ term $(0 \leq j \leq kn)$, is:

$$\sum_{i_1 + \cdots + i_k = j} p_{1i_1} p_{2i_2}\cdots p_{ki_k}.$$

For example, suppose $k = 3$, and we want to find the coefficient in $P(x)$ of the $x^2$ $(j=2)$ term.

We take all ordered triples of non-negative integers whose sum is two:

$$(i_1,i_2,i_3) \in \lbrace (2,0,0), (0,2,0), (0,0,2), (1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1) \rbrace.$$

The $j^\text{th}$ coefficient of $P(x)$ is then:

$$p_{12}p_{20} p_{30} + p_{10}p_{22} p_{30} + p_{10}p_{20} p_{32} + p_{11}p_{21} p_{30} + p_{11}p_{20} p_{31} + p_{10}p_{21} p_{31}.$$

Comment: So, if I want to find the sum of the coefficients upto $ k^t$$^h$ term a naive approach will be finding coefficients for all $i^t$$^h$ terms(i<k) and sum it up together? I wonder if there is an efficient approach...

Comment: No.  What I have written is that you can express the coefficient of the $j^\text{th}$ term of $P$ in terms of the coefficients of $P_1,...,P_k$.  There is only one way to approach this problem without any extra information about these polynomials.